# Folders disappearing from Launchpad

Tags: macos, applications, mojave, launchpad

I have a problem with Launchpad in macOS Mojave 10.14. It was already present in previous versions of macOS.

Sometimes I start my Mac and I find the Launchpad completely messy. All of the folders that I have created are gone, disappeared (only a fews of them are present): all the apps are outside. The only thing I can do is to re-arrange the apps. That's very annoying.

What can I do to prevent this behaviour?